# LWC: Import JSON from a zip Static Resource

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, zip, platformresourceloader

The `platformResourceLoader` module only offers `loadScript` and `loadStyle`. Is there a way to load JSON files from a zip Static Resource?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a simple XMLHttpRequest:

```
import MYJSON from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myjsonfile';
```

...

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", MYJSON);
xhr.onload = () => this.data = xhr.responseText;
xhr.send(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

I favor using `fetch` over `XMLHttpRequest` since fetch allows to work with Promises easily.

```
import MYJSON from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/myjsonfile';
```

```
  connectedCallback() {
    fetch(MYJSON)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => console.log(data));
  }
```

Comment: This works out really well.  Too bad no async/await in LWC yet.

Comment: Async/await are supported. Is a particular Usecase not working for you?

Comment: OK rad, I didn't realize that and the standard ES8 code I was trying to implement over in LWC didn't work as written, so I'll retry.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your JSON file in a Javascript file. An example is shown below. I created a file called test.js and uploaded to static resource with name test

```
"use strict"

window.myObj = {
"colors": [
  {
    "color": "black",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
      "hex": "#000"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "white",
    "category": "value",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [0,0,0,1],
      "hex": "#FFF"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "red",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [255,0,0,1],
      "hex": "#FF0"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "blue",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [0,0,255,1],
      "hex": "#00F"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "yellow",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "primary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [255,255,0,1],
      "hex": "#FF0"
    }
  },
  {
    "color": "green",
    "category": "hue",
    "type": "secondary",
    "code": {
      "rgba": [0,255,0,1],
      "hex": "#0F0"
     }
   },
  ]
};
```

You can now load this JSON into webcomponent using `platformResourceLoader` as below

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import testlib from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/testjs';


export default class Testcmp extends LightningElement {

libInitialized = false;

renderedCallback() {
    if (this.libInitialized) {
        return;
    }
    this.d3Initialized = true;

    loadScript(this, testlib).then(() => { 
        console.log(window.myObj);
    });
  }
}
```

Note that there is also another way to do this is by using a service component only to hold data export it as [Javascript function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_share_code).

Comment: You could, but complicated :p

Comment: What advantage an xmlhttprequest has over wrapping as js object ?

Comment: The main point, I guess, is that you can load any static resource you want (image, json, csv, etc). Also, you don't need to remember to add more code to the file, you can use it as is. There's nothing wrong with this answer, it's just unnecessary to go through the extra steps.

Comment: Got it! That makes sense!!

Comment: That's a creative hack! Although in real-life it's not always possible to do the required prep work (wrapping Javascript around JSON).